# Two windows open when I login into my application

Tags: android, android-intent

When I open my app and press the phone's button to see all the opened application, I see the `LoginActivity` AND another window that is the `HomeActivity` that was launch just after the login screen. I don't know if i'm being clear here, I probably don't have the right word to describe it. Don't hesitate to ask more detail if it's unclear...

I don't understand why it's appearing now, I didn't modify the way I launch my activity since a while...

**In the LoginActivity code:**

```
private void startHomeActivity() {

    if (dialog != null && dialog.isVisible())
        dialog.dismiss();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityHome.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    // Smooth transition.
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 500);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
}
```

**In the manifest:**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activityv2.ActivityLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activityv2.ActivityHome"
        android:label="Security Agent"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tag_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say. What happens if you click on the window that says `Login`? I think it'll open the home activity, and it's just a system 'bug'. And if not, then you need to kill the Login activity if you do not want it to be shown after you've logged in.

Comment: Why are you adding those flags to the intent?  What effect are you trying to get from them?  Because they're the reason why.

Comment: When I click on the LoginActivity, it just reopen the login activity. And If I log back in, still the same. I got 2 window...Its weird

Comment: @GabeSechan Because back then when I added those flag, it was to avoid pressing back buttons to return to the LoginActivity... And it worked great...until now :(

Comment: If you want that, then just finish() the login activity after the startactivity, and remove the flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should close your `LoginActivity` if the user logs in successfully - this way, only your `HomeActivity` will display.

So perhaps call `finish()` - immediately after the line starting the new `Activity`:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(intent);
           //kill current activity (LoginActivity?)
            finish();
        }
    }, 500);
```

I hope this helps.